# Is there a function that prints the color of an HTML object?

Tags: html

i need to know if there is a function that returns the color code of h2 (or the string). So in this example I return 'blue'. And if it exists if it is possible to request it on specific id or class, then if for example h2 had id = "title_blue" I could ask directly on '#title_blue'? Thank you very much!

> 

```
<h2 style="color: blue">COLORED TEXT</h2>
```

Comment: HTML is not a programming language. This is a markup language. Generally the programming language that uses functions to create an HTML file is JavaScript, but not necessarily. So I think you should precise the programming language you want to use to make the task you want.

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('test').style.color)
```

```html
<h2 id = 'test' style="color: blue">COLORED TEXT</h2>
```

Comment: Ok, and how can I put it in a variable?

Comment: let myColor = document.getElementById('test').style.color;